# why is setOnClickListener called twice?

Tags: java, android

this code is called from my Activity `onCreate()`:

```
    private void setOnClickListeners() {

        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onSignClicked();
            }
        });

    mForgotYourText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onRemindClicked();
        }
        });

..

}
```

`mLoginButton` is a LinearLayout with a textView inside it

`mForgotYourText` is a TextView

while debugging I see that the  `mLoginButton.setOnClickListener` assignment is called twice.

whereas `mForgotYourText.setOnClickListener` is assignment called only once as expected.

why is the difference? is it because eventHandling propagation?

if so - why `public void onClick(View v)` cannot return boolean to stop propagation?

a even more strange thing is that this code is called 3 times,

working on the same element `mLoginButton`:

```
    mPhoneNumberField.setInputTextOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Make sure you dont have set android:onClick="onSignClicked()" on mLoginButton by xml

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't have `android:onClick` in your xml, the onClick will only be called once.
2. This is called three times *at least*, because of the way `onTouch` works:
   It can be used to track touch movements - It continuously reports the touch position together with the current action - `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE` or `ACTION_UP`. And that's the reason why you are seeing it being called three times. If you check `event.getAction()`, you'll see the three actions above will each appear once.

   To avoid this behaviour, just check the action. Typically you want to make sure it's `ACTION_UP`:

   ```
   if (Event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
   ....
   ```

Answer (score -1):

On touch devices you need to  set it on leave (because you pressing the button and its actually clicked when you kate your finger from the button)

Comment: what do you mean `on leave` how?